# Layout for pages generated from a collection with output set to true

Tags: jekyll

I build a style guide in Jekyll and have a collection set up for each of the components. It uses only front-matter to display data about the styles. A file could look like this:

```
---
title: "Button Big Fixed"
type: interactive elements
description: "A big button with a fixed height."

code:
 html: |
  <button class="expanderBtn icon">Button</button>
 css: |
  .test { 
    font-size: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
  }

colors:
  - name: Brand Blue
    hex: "#006CFF"
    notes: Used as the background
  - name: Hover
    hex: "#7FB5FF"
    notes: Brand Blue with 50% opacity
  - name: Clicked
    hex: "#4091FF"
    notes: Brand Blue with 75% opacity
  - name: Text
    hex: "#000000"
    notes: Text should be black for best legibility
---
```

Now, for a permalink feature, I'd like to use output: true. However, the documents that get generated are empty because I only use front matter.

Is there any way to set a custom template or something similar, so I can render the front matter on the page generated by output: true?

Comment: It's written in the doc http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a default template for each collection in your _config.yml. This looks like this:

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ''
    values:
      layout: 'page'
  - scope:
      path: ''
      type: 'guides'
    values:
      layout: 'guide'
```

It means: use the page.html file in the _layouts directory for everything except for the collection 'guides'. For 'guides' you should use guide.html. Create this file in your _layouts folder. In this guide.html file you call parts of the frontmatter by using:

```
page.title
page.description
page.etc
```

Good luck!